# JavaScript - CSS width based on value

Tags: javascript, css

I've got a little thing set up with two bars:

```
<div class="bars">
<div class="bar bar-1" value="15"></div>
<div class="bar bar-2" value="7.5"></div>
</div>
```

I want the largest bar (by value) to be at 100% width at all times, and the smaller bar to scale accordingly. In this example, bar-2 would be half the size of bar-1.

Comment: What have you already tried to accomplish this? Do you use any framework like jquery, react, vue.js, angular for binding? Do you want to solve it in vanilla JS?

Comment: In this case you can use data attribute like data-value="15"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple and "quick & dirty" solution using your code - as you did not provide any more information

https://jsfiddle.net/b53pzfdj/

```js
// get all bars
var bars = document.getElementsByClassName('bar')

// determine the highest value
var longest = 0;

for (var bar of bars) {
    if (parseInt(bar.getAttribute('value')) > longest) {
        longest = parseInt(bar.getAttribute('value'));
    }
}

// set width relative to the highest value for each bar
for (var bar of bars) {
    bar.style.width = `${parseInt(bar.getAttribute('value')) / longest * 100}%`;
}
```